# Use .json file values in Node.js without restarting server

Tags: json, node.js

Let's say I have some.json:

```
"key" : "value"
```

I started node.js server.

After that I changed some.json by hand:

```
"key" : "another value"
```

When I read this file I see that "key" is "value" but I need "another value".

How to do this without restarting the server?

Comment: How did you read the file? With fs.ReadStream? https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_readstream

Comment: With require().key

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon), a utility that will monitor for any changes in your source and automatically restart our server. You can install it globally:

```
$ npm install -g nodemon
```

Once installed, start `node.js` server with `nodemon` instead of node, for example:

```
$ nodemon server.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me a little bit of looking around, but watching a file may help you with what you need, using chokidar.

Here's what I did:

```
export let config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(process.env.CONFIG_PATH!, 'utf-8'));

// Config Watch
chokidar.watch(process.env.CONFIG_PATH!).on('change', (path: string) => {
    config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(process.env.CONFIG_PATH!, 'utf-8'));
});
```

And it worked perfectly :-)